# Angular Material - mat-form-field prevent click events using stopPropagation is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

Unable to click the radio buttons within `mat-label` of the `mat-form-field`. The click events on the `mat-form-field` are passed to the select field. Is there a way to prevent that behavior?

I tried `<mat-form-field (click)=$event.stopPropagation()` but did not work.

[image]

```html
<mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>
       <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
         <span>Title</span>
         <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="groupSelection" name="groupSelection">
           <mat-radio-button value="option A">
              Option A
           </mat-radio-button>
           <mat-radio-button  value="option B">
              Option B
           </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </div>
   </mat-label>
   <mat-select [(ngModel)]="optionSelection">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="optionVal">
          {{option}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

## Working Demo

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-button-demo?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you reproduce it on Stackblitz?

Comment: updated with Stackblitz demo.

Comment: So far I got it to select the radio buttons, but every time I click on the radio buttons, the select opens up... I figure that is not the desired result.  The radio buttons DO get selected though

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a couple of things here to make it work. I separated the radio buttons and the select by divs.  Then I stopped propagation on the radio buttons and the title span.  Ugh, that was ugly

```
<h1>Radio Buttons in Mat-label (unable to click)</h1>

<mat-form-field floatLabel="always" style="width: 300px">
  <div>
  <mat-label>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
      <span (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Title</span>
      <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="groupSelection" style="margin-left: 50px">
        <mat-radio-button value="optionA" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"> Option A </mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="optionB" style="margin-left: 25px"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
          Option B
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
  </mat-label>
</div>
  <div>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</div>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot. Yeah, that's the same as moving the label outside mat-form-field and using some CSS to make it look like the floating label. Maybe that is the only option.